# CSS background:url() on external server

Tags: css, background-image, external

I am using the following css rule:

```
background: url("http://example.com/background.jpg");
```

It is not working and I suppose it is because referring to external servers is not supported. Is this true? If so, what kind of workaround I might use?

Not sure if it's relevant, but I need this inline. Testing right now on JSFiddle.

Comment: remove quotes and it should work.

Comment: Can you try it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and check it out? The quotes should be there @bhups

Comment: Perhaps the website disabled hotlinking?

Comment: If it's not working and you are sure URL is correct, then the source of the image may be using hotlinking protection, where they check the referrer, and not serving you the image.

Comment: may be you container dont have height,width or padding oe may be your URL is wrong

Comment: May you post the all the css rules of the container?

Comment: Quote can be there or not with your present url, its fine as long as you dont have any special chars conflicting in the url, in that case you can use quote or escape the charachters

Answer (score 9):

There may be 2 reasons why your background is not working

1. Your container doesn't have height, width or padding (no area to show the background)
2. The URL you specified is broken or incorrect. There is no image at the URL you specified.

Otherwise, your `background: url("http://example.com/background.jpg");` is **Correct**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was resolved or not but I had a similar problem and I found a simple solution. First off, I used background-image instead of background. Second, I made sure to include the full url. So instead of background: url("http://example.com/background.jpg"); I would put background-image: url("http://www.example.com/background.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

It does work. There must be something wrong with your URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebLQQ/

Comment: For some reason, even the fiddle fails to load the image. I am a Chrome

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno The placekitten service seems to not be currently working.